# Каким способом я могу заставить форму выдавать определенные данные по паролю?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Может не так скорректировал вопрос, сейчас объясню. Есть легкая форма:

```html
<div id="login">
  <form name='form-login'>
    <span class="lock"></span>
    <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password" maxlength="10">       
    <input type="submit" value="test">
  </form>
</div>
```

Каким способом я могу осуществить проверку на правильность вводимого пароля и, если пароль введен верно, осуществить загрузку нужного файла? Мне хочется увидеть примеры, нужны ли какие библиотеки для реализации задуманного, где содержать нужный для разблокировки пароль и как его скрыть.

Comment: Тут 2 основных варианта: с перезагрузкой страницы (полностью на сервере) или без перезагрузки(используя js). Какой вам нужен?

Comment: Использовать js в моем случае будет хорошим вариантом.

Comment: Какие языки программирования поддерживает ваш веб-хостинг?

Comment: @demol0cv я пока что пользуюсь локальным веб сервером.

Answer (score 1):

При отправки данных с формы используются два метода **POST** и **GET**, указываются в теге  например, также нужно указать скрипт, который обработает запрос, в атрибуте *action*. Подробнее здесь [htmlbook.ru/html/form](http://htmlbook.ru/html/form). Пароли в скрипт нужно передавать GET-запросом.

```
<div id="login">
  <form name="form-login" action="login.php" method="GET">
    <span class="lock"></span>
    <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password" maxlength="10" name="pswd">       
    <input type="submit" value="test">
  </form>
</div>
```

Далее на сервере должен быть расположен скрипт обработки данных с формы, назовём его *login.php* и представим в нём примерно следующее содержание:

```
<?php
$password = $_GET["pswd"] //pswd это будет имя инпута, в который пароль писали
if($password == "1q2w3e3r4") //здесь проверяем пароль
    {
        echo ("<img src=\"picture.png\">");
    } else 
    {
        echo ("<h1>Неверный пароль!</h1>");
    }
?>
```

Это в общих чертах, на самом деле нужно пароль в зашифрованном виде хранить и желательно не в самой программе.

Если требуется без перезагрузки страницы, то тут да, нужна библиотека jQuery как минимум.

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Буду копать дальше.